# Javascript: How do I make a calendar selection?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a reminder-type program for school, and so far the user is presented with a few options.

The first is to enter the name of the reminder, and then replace the text "currently not set" to their input. **this bit works**.

However, I now need the other option to present the user with calendar, to then select a date from - and then going further slightly, how would the page check if the current time matches the time they have chosen?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function enterTime()
{
    var reminder_time = //????
}

function enterNew()
{
    var reminder_name = prompt("Please enter the name of the reminder:")
    document.getElementById("nameOfReminder").innerHTML = reminder_name
}

function warning()
{
        return "Warning! Refreshing will make you lose all of your data.";
}
window.onbeforeunload = warning;
</script>
```

Comment: you need to use the [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object to compare times, see the examples at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use for this a jQuery plugin - [Date and Time picker](http://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/)

Example html:

```
<input type="text" name="date" class="datepicker">
```

javascript:

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    mask:'39-19-9999 29:59:59',
    format:'d-m-Y H:i:s'
});
```

Comment: Thanks. If I change `type="text"` to `type="date"` this works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has no built-in calendar user interface. I see from the `script` tags and use of `prompt` in your question that you're using JavaScript in a browser: *Very* up-to-date browsers may provide one on an `<input type="date">` field (one of the new types defined by HTML5), but support varies. Otherwise, you might look at any of the several hundred "datepicker" libraries out there. One example is jQuery UI, but it's just one popular one of many.

Alternately, you could allow the user to type in a date via `prompt`, and then parse it. There's only *very* minimal date parsing built into JavaScript itself, so again you might turn to libraries like MomentJS or similar.

Just for the sake of an example, and again **there are lots of other libraries out there**, here's how you might collect the date and time using jQuery UI and parse it with MomentJS:

```js
// Tell jquery UI to make "#the-date" a datepicker
$("#the-date").datepicker();

// Respond to clicks on the button
$("#add-button").click(function() {
  var theDate = $("#the-date").val();
  var theTime = $("#the-time").val();
  var dateObject = moment(theDate);
  
  snippet.log("theDate (as a string): " + theDate);
  snippet.log("theTime (as a string): " + theTime);
  snippet.log("dateObject's default toString: " +
              dateObject.toString());
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>
    Choose a date:
    <input type="text" id="the-date">
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Choose the time:
    <input type="txt" id="the-time">
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" id="add-button" value="Add">
</div>
```

There are also libraries (and "plugins" to jQuery UI) that provide date *and* time pickers.